# Bash No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

When I do

```
for files in ~/Desktop/mydir/*.text; 
do
           mycommand  "$files" > "out.txt"
done
```

It works fine. But when I do the same thing with

```
mycommand "$files" > "~/Desktop/out.txt"
```

I get `~/Desktop/out.txt: No such file or directory.`
Why?

Comment: Double quotes prevent expansion of `~`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I really just started with bash. Can you please tell me the difference between "$files" and $files?

Comment: When you write `$files`, the result is re-scanned for whitespace and wildcards. When you write `"$files"` the result is treated as a single argument, with no further processing.

Comment: Usually you should put quotes around variables, as you rarely want the result to be split into multiple words. For instance, if a filename contains spaces, you want it to be a single argument, not split up.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I just started with bash and I love it so far. Could you please suggest me good online sources to learn bash scripting?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with tutorials, so I don't know what to refer you to.

Comment: Ok I'll find out myself. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch at www.tldp.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the tilde out of the quotes so it can be properly expanded:

```
mycommand "$files" > ~/Desktop/out.txt
```

You can also use `${HOME}` if any subsequent part of your path contains spaces and you want to quote the whole path:

```
mycommand "$files" > "${HOME}/Desktop/out.txt"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between "$files" and $files?

Comment: `"$files"` will be treated as a single command line argument and does not require that you escape certain special characters such as spaces. `$files` will be evaluated inline and if any spaces exist in the variable then they will cause both sides of the space to be treated as two separate arguments to your command.

Comment: `~/Desktop/out.txt` doesn't need quoting, regardless of whether ~ expands to a path with spaces in it (just like for globs). `echo ~` doesn't fix anything, it only introduces new bugs.

Comment: @thatotherguy Nice! Also, I totally forgot about `$HOME`. I've updated my answer to be more accurate about working with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Because quoting the filename suppresses most characters' special meanings to the shell.  In particular, it suppresses the meaning of '~/' at the start of the file name.